# Dicts in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a multidimensionnal dict, I need to return a specific value.

```
ConsomRatio={"DAP_Local":[],"MAP11_52":[]}
ConsomRatio["DAP_Local"].append({"Ammonia":"0.229", "Amine":"0.0007"})
ConsomRatio["MAP11_52"].append({"Ammonia":"0.138", "Fuel":"0.003"})

print(ConsomRatio["DAP_Local"])
```

The result of the print is:

```
[{'Ammonia': '0.229', 'Amine': '0.0007'}]
```

My question is : Is there a way to return the value of "Ammonia" only, in "DAP_Local" ?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain more exactly what you want? Why are you putting lists inside the dict anyhow?

Comment: Actually, I wanted to use multi-dimensional dicts, but got lost into the syntax, so went back and used lists inside the dict. Multi-dimensional dicts are more efficient in my case.

Comment: dicts are really rather efficient -- at least in your case. With simpler needs as yours, lists can be used and than they are more efficient.

Comment: I only used some of the data to make sure my problem is clear. I actually have a big amount of data, that is why I thought dicts would be way more efficient.

Comment: Don't worry: in spite of my comments, dicts are really efficient in Python and you can handle big amounts of data with them, at least when you don't try to handle whole databases (multiple GBs of data with them).

I guess, it is for a students project?

Comment: @Juergen It is for my final year internship

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71688/discussion-between-juergen-and-imane-dergal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you putting lists in your dict, anyhow? You can just use dicts inside your main dict.

You can have multidimensional dicts also without the lists, e.g.:

```
ConsomRatio = {}
ConsomRation["DAP_Local"] = {"Ammonia":"0.229", "Amine":"0.0007"}
ConsomRatio["MAP11_52"] = {"Ammonia":"0.138", "Fuel":"0.003"}

print(ConsomRatio["DAP_Local"]["Ammonia"])
```

will give the desired result without the extra effort with the list.

You can get even shorter in Python:

```
ConsomRatio = {
   "DAP_Local": {"Ammonia":"0.229", "Amine":"0.0007"},
   "MAP11_52" : {"Ammonia":"0.138", "Fuel":"0.003"},
}

print(ConsomRatio["DAP_Local"]["Ammonia"])
```

To also answer your latest question (in your second comment):

```
to_produce  = 'DAP_Local'
ingredience = 'Ammonia'
print('To produce {to_produce} we need {amount} of {ingredience}'.format(
      to_produce=to_produce, ingredience=ingredience,
      amount=ConsomRatio[to_produce].get(ingredience, '0.0')))
```

I hope, that helps!

It gets even better:

```
for product, ingred_list in ConsomRatio.items(): 
    for iname, ivalue in ingred_list.items(): 
        print('To produce {to_produce} we need {amount} of {ingredience}'
              .format(to_produce=product, ingredience=iname, 
                      amount=ivalue))
```

Comment: And what if I need to use the values returned in print ? Meaning print a sentence that says " To produce DAP_Local, we need 0.229 of Ammonia "

Comment: @imanedergal: I added a short code snippet that shows an example how to do it.

Comment: It really does! Thank you very much!

Comment: @imanedergal: I changed my last example a little. Since it is for an internship, your coding should be rock-solid, of course. With the get-method of dicts you get a default value, when a key does not exist (or in this case, when an ingredients is not used).

Comment: @imanedergal: In case, you haven't seen: I added an additional example to my answer, that shows how to output all the information in your dicts.

Answer (score 7):

You can get to it like this. You're appending your `dict` to a `list`, so you must select the correct index in the `list` where the `dict` is located. In this case the first element in the list or index `0`.

```
ConsomRatio["DAP_Local"][0]["Ammonia"]
```

By the way, depending on what you are trying to achieve you might wanna take a look at the other answers for different implementations of multi-dimensional dicts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I had no idea I had to use an index.And yes, I think multi-dimensional dicts are more appropriate in my case!

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are of course correct, but have you considered using a "dict of dicts"? i.e.:

```
ConsomRatio={"DAP_Local":{},"MAP11_52":{}}
ConsomRatio["DAP_Local"].update({"Ammonia":"0.229", "Amine":"0.0007"})
ConsomRatio["MAP11_52"].update({"Ammonia":"0.138", "Fuel":"0.003"})

print ConsomRatio["DAP_Local"]["Ammonia"]
0.229
```

Answer (score 3):

since `print(ConsomRatio["DAP_Local"])` returns an array of length 1, you need to select the index 0, then key off the 'Ammonia' value as above.

if `print(ConsomRatio["DAP_Local"])` returned a dict, then no need to have the `[0]` and `print(ConsomRatio["DAP_Local"]['Amomonia'])` would have worked